# Is it possible to walk a wpf TreeView via TreeViewItems instead of its bound content?

Tags: wpf, treeview, treeviewitem

I'm having real problems with `TreeViews` `BringIntoView` implementation when trying to select things in the tree that are bound via `ItemSource` and `ItemTemplate`. It just doesn't work, I've tried pretty much all the fancy ways i could find via google and most don't work and if they do the wrong thing is always selected.

It would be be easier for me if i could just walk the tree one level at a time via treeview items instead of the the things i'd bound in.

Is there a way of "mapping" my bound hierarchical data template items back as treeviewitems?

NOTE: it would appear part of the problem with bring into view is that the items im loading into the tree is done in a "lazy" manner where the children are created until they shown - i have to do it this way as the dataset is huge.

To summarize: I can quickly search through my dataset and ascertain a "nodes" full hierarchical path quite quickly i.e. i can get "root\p1\p2\p3\data" easily enough, but I cant get a treeview thats bound to the dataset to display it using bringintoview. If I could walk the tree using treevitems i could find the node myself and call bringintoview on that. thats the plan anyway.

mucho tacks.

EDIT:

After some more searching I have found this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2010/02/23/finding-an-object-treeviewitem.aspx. Which works buts also has problems - I can't initially expand the root object, and I can't work out how to seperate the ItemsPanel and ItemContainerStyle into toplevel styles/resources so i can share them about my other treeviews easily.

Comment: Can't you just get the TreeViewItem by the TreeView's [ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.containerfromitem.aspx) method?

Comment: fully agree with @Clemens, `ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem()` is the way to go.

Comment: Can't use something that always returns null. After some searching I have found this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2010/02/23/finding-an-object-treeviewitem.aspx